# Bug in my Erase() function for linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to pass a tester program, and i pass all tests except when it comes to my erase function, the program crashes.

my best guess is possibly a front or back sentinel node is being erased. or memory leak.

Comment: You should provide a minimal reproduction of the problem, this is way too much code.

Comment: there is a problem with the 2 param erase function and i do not know what it is

Comment: once it prints "line 7 test" the program crashes and never reaches "line 8 test" at the very bottom of main

Comment: You didn't even provide the erase function.

Comment: @Kelm  it's clearly the first code block

Comment: Ah my bad, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt anyone is willing to read all this code and find the bug for you, especially in the absence of an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). At first glance there's something obviously wrong in the function `void erase(iterator it)`

> `left->next_ = right;`
>
> `right->prev_ = left;`

You did not check if either of right or left is null, which occurs if you delete at the beginning or at the end of your list. Also you should modify the list's `front_` and `back_` accordingly.

You can add a check before those assignments:

```
if(left)
    left->next_ = right;
else
    front_ = right;

if(right)
    right->prev_ = left;
else
    back_ = left;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136673/discussion-on-answer-by-a-s-h-bug-in-my-erase-function-for-linked-list).